# Are the foil cards distinguishable (regarding original color) on Magic Duels (MtG)?

Tags: magic-duels

I converted a card to foil on Xbox One and the color result wasn't as good as I was expecting.

The original card was a green one and the effect made it 'greyish', I don't know if I could differentiate blue and green cards, for example, after converting them to foil. I don't want to risk converting others, to later regret it.

It may be the case that the Xbox One version is not that good (regarding the color), or there may be some other problem with my TV. I'm planning to invest time and effort on the PC version, so I want to know if the color can be differentiated once converted.

Comment: We can answer the part about the cards being able to be differentiated.  We *can't* answer if they're beautiful enough.  I'd recommend removing that from your question.

Comment: Wait, so what's the question exactly? Is it as your title states? I don't want to disrupt the intent of your question, so if you could put a little question blurb at the bottom of the paragraphs that'd be great.

Comment: I'm changing the title to better reflect your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, judge for yourself.

I recently encountered a foiled blue card and shot some screen.
Compare these pictures to your foiled green card, note how the border is blueish on all of these:

[image]

In general to me it's a bit hard to distinguish foiled multicolored cards or gates, but monos are easily spotted.

Comment: This answers my question, thanks. When mono, they're clearly distinguishable, when foiled they are all too similar. They should have reinforced the main color on the foiled cards.